# .net 2.0 inheritence with namespaced baseclass

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

Trying to keep my code out of App_Code,

have two classes:

```
namespace BackEnd
{

    public class PubTool 
    {

    }

}
```

and

```
namespace BackEnd
{

    public class Hub : PubTool
    {

        private string _hubName;
        private DataTable _data;

        public Hub(string hubId)
        {
            GetData(hubId);
        }

    }
}
```

if the classes are in one file all is good, but if they are in two different files, I get an error that PubTool isn't found, so I'm sure I'm missing a reference somewhere but I don't know where it should go.

Comment: Are the two different files also in two different projects?

Comment: I am assuming same solution same project?

Comment: right clicking the project is the default namespace set as 'BackEnd'? (assuming it is a one namespace project)

Comment: two different cs files, in same directory/project

Comment: Is this a web project or a web application?  If you have code still in the App_Code folder, it can be compiled differently..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, web projects don't work that way, everything has to reside in App_Code

Answer (score 0):

Is There nested namespaces going on?  Try fully qualifying it and seeing what exists:

```
BackEnd.PubTool
```

control + space bar usually brings up intellisense in visual studio

Looking at your posted code I did notice that you were using a DataTable object, this would require a using directive.

```
namespace BackEnd
{
    using System.Data;

    public class Hub : PubTool
    {
        private string _hubName;
        private DataTable _data;

        public Hub(string hubId)
        {
            GetData(hubId);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Qualifying it gets this error `The type or namespace name 'PubTool' does not exist in the namespace 'BackEnd' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`